# Is it possible to execute Cucumber Tests multiple times based on tags?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

Providing I have the following Feature File with two scenarios that have different tags such as the below:

```
Feature: Home Feature
  Tests for the Home page

@Desktop @Tablet @Mobile
Scenario: I should see the correct page title
  Given I navigate to the Home page
  Then the page title should read "test"

@Desktop @Tablet
Scenario: I should see the correct body text
  Given I navigate to the Home page
  Then the body text should read "test"
```

And I also have the following `Hooks`, `ChromeWebController`, `HomeSteps` & `RunCucumberTest` classes, would it be possible to run the scenarios multiple times on different devices. For example, could the scenario with `@Desktop`, `@Tablet` & `@Mobile` be executed three times, once on each device, whilst, the scenario with `@Desktop` `@Tablet` be executed two times, again, once on each device? Or would this require a different approach?

```
package hooks;

import controllers.ChromeWebController;
import fixtures.HomePageFixture;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;

public class Hooks {
  private final ChromeWebController chromeWebController;
  private Scenario scenario;

  public Hooks(ChromeWebController chromeWebController) {
    this.chromeWebController = chromeWebController;
  }

  @Before
  public void beforeScenarioSteps(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
    chromeWebController.setDeviceType(scenario.getSourceTagNames());
    chromeWebController.setupChromeDriver();
    scenario.log(HomePageFixture.HOME_PAGE_URL);
  }

  @After
  public void afterScenarioSteps() {
    chromeWebController.quitWebDriver();
  }
}
```

```
package controllers;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class ChromeWebController {
  private WebDriver webDriver;
  private String deviceType;

  public ChromeWebController() {
  }

  public void setupChromeDriver() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();

    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    options.addArgument("--window-size=1366,768");

    if (getDeviceType().equals("Tablet")) {
      mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPad");
      options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    } else if (getDeviceType().equals("Mobile")) {
      mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone X");
      options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    }

    this.webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  }

  public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
    if (webDriver == null) {
      throw new WebDriverException("WebDriver has not been created, please ensure setupChromeDriver has been called.");
    }
    return webDriver;
  }

  public void quitWebDriver() {
    webDriver.quit();
  }

  public void setDeviceType(Collection<String> scenarioTags) {
    if (deviceType != null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("deviceType can only be set once.");
    }

    var scenarioTagsToString = scenarioTags.toString();

    if (scenarioTagsToString.contains("@Desktop")) {
      deviceType = "Desktop";
    } else if (scenarioTagsToString.contains("@Tablet")) {
      deviceType = "Tablet";
    } else if (scenarioTags.toString().contains("@Mobile")) {
      deviceType = "Mobile";
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Desktop/Tablet/Mobile scenario tag has not been implemented in the feature file.");
    }
  }

  public String getDeviceType() {
    if (deviceType.equals("")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("deviceType has not been set.");
    }

    return deviceType;
  }
}
```

```
package steps.home;

import controllers.ChromeWebController;
import fixtures.HomePageFixture;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class HomeSteps{
    private final WebDriver webDriver;

    public HomeSteps(ChromeWebController chromeWebController) {
        this.webDriver = chromeWebController.getWebDriver();
    }

    @Given("I navigate to the Home page")
    public void iNavigateToTheHomePage() {
        webDriver.get(HomePageFixture.HOME_PAGE_URL);
    }

    @Then("The body text should read {string}")
    public void theBodyTextShouldRead(String expectedText) {
        String actualText = webDriver.findElement(By.id("test")).getText();

        assert (actualText).equals(expectedText);
    }
}
```

```
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@CucumberOptions(publish = true)
public class RunCucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u tried with multiple runners with the `tags` option set with each device type. `tags = @desktop` etc etc.

Comment: @Grasshopper That's a good shout. I'm not sure why I didn't think to try that! I'll give that a go shortly and let you know the results.

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried that, the problem I've faced is that when setting the tags to be executed to either Tablet or Mobile, it still passes Desktop into chromeWebController.setDeviceType(Collection<String> scenarioTags) as the first tag is Desktop in the Feature file

Comment: U also need to modify the Before hook by adding tag filter to the annotation. U will end up having as many Before hooks as devices. For example for `Mobile` type the Before annotation becomes `@Before("@Mobile")`. In the hook just hardcode the device type to send to the `setDeviceType` method. U will need to change the `setDeviceType` argument type to take a String. This way cucumber should do all the work for you.

Comment: @Grasshopper I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding but the problem still persists. I want the Feature files to be able to have all three tags if necessary. E.g. if the Feature file has all 3 tags, then all test runners will pick that test up. The problem if I use ```@Before("Mobile")``` is that if a Scenario has all three tags ```@Desktop @Tablet @Mobile``` then it will try and use all the ```@Before``` Hooks

Comment: My bad. U r right. Tried a solution by reducing the hook visibility and adding the glue option. Added as an answer as hard to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two (basically equal to the devices) packages for device specific hook.

Hook for mobile type in package `mobile`

```
package mobile;

public class MobileHook {

    @Before("@mobile")
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println("MOBILE");
    }
}
```

Hook for tablet type in package `tablet`

```
package tablet;

public class TabletHook {
    
    @Before("@tablet")
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("TABLET");
    }
}
```

The common glue code should be kept in a separate package say `stepdefs`.

Modify the runners accordingly.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "summary" }, tags = "@mobile", glue = {"mobile", "stepdefs"})
public class RunCukeMobileIT


@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "summary" }, tags = "@tablet", glue = {"tablet", "stepdefs"})
public class RunCukeTabletIT
```

Basically reducing the visibility to the relevant hook. Guess u will need to modify the code which initializes the driver.